# How do I set foreignObject width and height in stenciljs?

Tags: typescript, svg, jsx, stenciljs, foreignobject

I'm trying to create a StencilJS component that uses an SVG and contains some HTML, but I get the error: 'TypeError: setting getter-only property "height"' whenever I load the component.

I have tested the HTML on its own and it displays correctly, I'm setting the width and height of the foreignObject to 100% to fill the svg, but setting it in the StencilJS component causes the error.
I also checked [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) and the attributes don't seem to be read-only.

Here's the code that I'm using:

```js
import { Component, h } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'my-component',
  styleUrl: 'my-component.css',
  shadow: true
})
export class MyComponent {

  render() {
    return (
    <svg>
      <foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>
        <div>SOME TEXT</div>
      </foreignObject>
    </svg>
    );
  }
}
```

It's just the basic component generated from the stencilJS init cli

Comment: I just tried it in my v1.1.3 app and I don't get any errors. According to the [changelog](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#-120-2019-07-24) they fixed a `foreignObject` bug described in [this issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/1733). Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'd scaffold-ed the component using `npm init stencil` and didn't check what version that applied. I was using version 1.0.7 but updating to the latest version using `npm install @stencil/core@latest` fixed the issue.